# Check if Set of Object contain an Object with this attribute

Tags: java, set

Consider i have a List Of Objects, and i convert it to a Set to make some actions like this :

```
List<User> listUser = new ArrayList<>();
listUser.add(new User(1, "user1"));
listUser.add(new User(2, "user2"));
listUser.add(new User(3, "user3"));

Set<User> myset = new HashSet<>(listUser);
```

I know there are a `contains(Object o)` but i want to check with the attributes of my Object.

My Question is What is the best way to check if the Set contain an Object with `ID = 1` or `user = "user1"` or any attribute

Thank you.

Comment: then there you need to use Map,  not Set, put id as key and you object as value

Comment: i can check with username or id or any attribute not just the id, this is just and example @subash

Comment: If you want to try something really fancy, you take advantage of [Java 8's Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/) support, basically, I'd look to filtering the set based on your critiria and see what you end up with

Comment: thank you @MadProgrammer i'm using Java 7 i don't think this is supported there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your `User` class override `equals`using just the ID? If so, you could use:

```
if (mySet.contains(new User(1, "irrelevant"));
```

Note that it's quite odd to have something called `mySet` which is actually a `List` rather than a `Set`... I'd consider either changing the name or the type. If you use `HashSet` you'll need to override `hashCode` as well as `equals`, but you should do that anyway to obey the normal contracts from `Object`.

If you want to be able to check by multiple different attributes - or if you don't want to override equality in `User` - then you could consider creating maps instead, e.g.

```
Map<Integer, User> usersById = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, User> usersByName = new HashMap<>();
...
```

Then you need to keep all the maps in sync, of course - and you need to consider what happens if you've got multiple users with the same name, etc.

Comment: If he changes the type to `List` he can use `list.stream().anyMatch(...)`, can't he?

Comment: Thank you for your help i appreciate it :)

Comment: @qwerty1423, first, he does not need a list to use a stream, that can be done with a set too. Second and more importantly, he said he’s using Java 7, so he cannot use streams at all (until he upgrades).

Comment: @OleV.V. I've missed the Java 7 part, you are right. Using `stream` and `anyMatch` with `HashSet` is not optimal though.

Comment: @qwerty1423, do you mean that if (with the right `equals` and `hashCode` methods) you can use `HashSet.contains()`, then this will be more efficient? Or did you have something else in mind when you said “not optimal”?

Comment: @OleV.V. Exactly, that's what i meant.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that you cannot use Java streams with Java 7 (they were introduced in Java 8). For Java 7 I would suggest an enhanced for loop in which you check your search condition (`if (u.getId() == 1)`) and act appropriately.

If you are ever getting a problem with the linear search that the `for` loop would do, you may build maps: `HashMap<Integer, User>` for allowing lookup by `ID` and `HashMap<String, User>` for lookup by user name. `Map.containsKey()` will tell you whether the map contains a specific user. You will need to take care that the maps contain all your users, and also that users are removed from the maps when deleted from your set/list, of course (oops, only saw now that Jon Skeet has already said all of this, sorry).

For anyone using Java 8 and reading along here, use of streams needs not be very fancy. A couple of examples:

```
    boolean containsUser1 = myset.stream().anyMatch(u -> u.getId() == 1);
```

This yieds `true`.

```
    User[] u1Array = myset.stream().filter(u -> u.getId() == 1).toArray(User[]::new);
    Set<User> u1Set = myset.stream().filter(u -> u.getUserName().equals("user1")).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Each of these two yield `[1 user1]` (the first one as an array, the second as s `Set`, obviously). Each use of a stream does a linear search behind the scenes.

That said, you *can* do fancy things with streams. I’ve found it a pleasure learning them and using them, look forward to that.

Answer (score 1):

Simpliest and fanciest way i think is to override equals method in your User class by just considering the id.

Then  you can use the contains method from the List interface

Comment: also remember to implement both `equals` and `hashCode` (the equivalence "contract")