# How to use contains() with substring

Tags: java, collections

i have an `ArryList` which have (name+"\n"+phoneNumber) so I wanna see if the name is containing with the list ? I used this code

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>(ContactsList);
if (set.contains(name))
{}
else
{
    ContactsList.add(name+"\n"+phoneNumber+"\n");
}
```

but how to use substring in contains so I get just the name from it to contain it with the name that I wanna add it to the list

and thanks

Comment: If you use a ``Set``, there's no need to check if a value already exists. Just add the new value. I don't understand this part: "how to use substring in contains so I get just the name from it" - you're not getting anything here. You can loop over all of the ``Set``'s values and see if one of them starts with a new name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the data in ArrayList as (name+"\n"+phoneNumber),
Create a class which 2 attributes name and phoneNumber, then create object of that class set both attributes and add that object in the ArrayList.

This is the right way of doing it and your problem also will be solved.

Comment: Let me add, the class could have a `toString` method that produces the string that you want with name and number on two lines.

Comment: For how to check whether your contact list contains an object with the given name, you may take inspiration from the answers to [Check if Set of Object contain an Object with this attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086329/check-if-set-of-object-contain-an-object-with-this-attribute).

Comment: Just override the equals and hashcode method in your class, then you can use the contains method which will compare the phoneNumber.